# iText7 Merge of Multiple PDF MemoryStreams Not Working

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, merge, itext7

I am trying to Generate a Single PDF File From Multiple Memory Streams, I am having a lot of trouble determining the proper way to merge 2 PDF MemoryStreams into one PDF MemoryStream that contains all the pages from both source PDF MemoryStreams. It seems simple and I think the code below is set up properly but the resulting PDF memory stream does not contain both the Files Combined.

I am having a lot of trouble determining the proper way to merge 2 PDF MemoryStreams into one PDF MemoryStream that contains all the pages from both source PDF MemoryStreams. It seems simple and I think the code below is set up properly but the resulting PDF memory stream does not Contain Merged Documents.

I have found multiple ways documented on the Internet as the "proper" way to do the merge. The actual sample code with iText 7 seems to be unusually complex (in that is mixes multiple concepts into one sample repeatedly - as in doesn't reduce the concept to the simplest possible code), and seems to fail to demonstrate simple concepts. For instance, their PDFMerge documentation has no sample code at all in the documentation (nor does anything else I looked at in the class documentation). The examples they have online actually always mix merging from files (not MemoryStreams or byte[]) with other concepts like adding page numbers or adding Table of Contents. So they never just show one concept and they never start with anything other than files. My PDFs are coming out of a database and we just need to merge them into one PDF memory stream and save it back out. My concern is that maybe I am not creating the MemoryStream properly when I initialize the PDFWriter. As none of their samples ever do anything but initial with an actual file, I was unable to confirm this was done properly. I also fully qualified all objects in the code because I want to leave the old iTextSharp code in place while I am upgrading to the new iText 7. This was done to make sure an iTextSharp object of the same name wasn't inadvertently being unknowingly used.

Also, in the interest of making the source as easy as possible to read I removed some of the declarations and initialization of objects being used. Everything was traced through and all values are fully loaded with proper values as you trace through the code. I am assuming the problem is that I didn't prepare the PDF objects properly or that I have to do something special with the PDFWriter on the Destination PDF Document (ms) before the the PDFMerge object.

```cs
             List<byte[]> streams = new List<byte[]>();
             somelist.ForEach(item=>
             {   
                using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
                {
                    pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
                    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(strContent, pdfWriter);
                    streams.Add(workStream.ToArray());
                    pdfWriter.Close();
                }
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);

            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(writer);

            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(document);

            streams.ForEach(stream =>
            {
                Stream msDoc = new MemoryStream(stream);

                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(msDoc));

                merger.Merge(doc, 1, doc.GetNumberOfPages());

                doc.Close();
            });

            ByteContent = ms.ToArray();

            document.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Merging is a really straightforward process:

```
        var SourceDocument1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC));
        var SourceDocument2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
        
        
        byte[] result;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
            var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            PdfMerger merge = new PdfMerger(pdfDocument);
            merge.Merge(SourceDocument1, 1, SourceDocument1.GetNumberOfPages())
                .Merge(SourceDocument2, 1, SourceDocument2.GetNumberOfPages());

            merge.Close();
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\file.pdf", result);
```

this will merge SRC with SRC1.

There are a lot of examples on [Github](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples), such as [this one](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/merge/MergeWithOutlines.cs) (there is also a whole folder with [merge examples](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/tree/develop/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/merge)).

I am writing the destination document in the end, just to make sure it's being created correctly, but you can do whatever you want to with the MemoryStream, of course.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, i'll try this for sure

Comment: Hi Andre i have tried almost all the examples that were there in that folder and none of them seems to be working for me, could you please provide me the solution by looping through documents and merging them as the solution that you have provided here doesn't quite suit my requirement at all

Comment: @HemanthMannam, so what you want is that a list of documents (SRC_n) gets merged into a single PDF in memory?

Comment: yes, i have a list f documents and when i try this strategy it was not working out for me so to currently merge the documents i have merged html and created a single pdf file

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between my solution, and what you're trying to achieve, I'm sorry. Maybe you can post some document examples?